# Encode string to json number in PHP with JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK without losing presicion

Tags: php, json, floating-point

If you run this code on PHP 5.3.10 in a 32 bit system (Windows7):

```
<?php

$object = new stdClass;
$object->flaotAsString = "8226347662.8374";

$json = json_encode($object, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

var_dump($object);
var_dump($json);
```

The output is:

```
object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'flaotAsString' => string '8226347662.8374' (length=15)
string '{"flaotAsString":8226347662.84}' (length=31)
```

I want the number in the json string be the same as the string in the object (without losing presicion).

Being a bug in PHP (I have not confirmed it) for this version and platform how could I do it?

Comment: Don't use JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK if you don't want the string to be unpacked.

Answer (score 0):

```
class stdClass#1 (1) {
  public $flaotAsString =>
  string(15) "8226347662.8374"
}
string(33) "{"flaotAsString":8226347662.8374}"
```

it works with PHP 5.5 on a 64 bits system. The problem must come from your plateform. If you can't upgrade to a 64 bits architecture, an ugly solution would be to work with string instead of int.

This problem has already been discussed here
http://grokbase.com/t/php/php-bugs/11ankwwn3n/php-bug-bug-60111-new-json-numeric-check-option-mangles-certain-values